# Get the email id based on user name in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, login

In the login page, I'm using the username instead of email. Fetching the email is not working and shows the empty page. Can please anyone help me.

```
echo $username = $login['username']; 
                    $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('r_user_dea', $username, 'like');                   

                    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
                    $list = $this->customerRepository->getList($searchCriteria);


                    if ($list->getTotalCount() > 0) {
                        foreach ($list->getItems() as $item) { 

                            echo $email = $item->getEmail(); exit; 
                            //$login['username'] = $email; 


                        }
                    }

$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('r_user_dea', $username, 'like');
```

in this line, `r_user_dea` is my custom attribute.

Comment: What is the `$list->getTotalCount()` result?

Comment: get the count of list

Comment: @venkataprasad Please try `echo $email = $item->getData('email');`

Comment: not working 
$userDea = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('r_user_dea', $username, 'like');  this syntax correct right @NalinSavaliya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection');
                $collection = $customerObj->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                              ->addAttributeToFilter('r_user_dea',$login['username'])
                              ->load();

               $cData=$collection->getData();

               $login['username'] = '';
                foreach($c_data as $data){
                     $email = $data['email'];
                }
                $login['username'] = $email;
```

Comment: Do not use ObjectManager Direct. It defeats the purpose of dependency injection.

Comment: Can you please tell me what issue occured in my answer? Because, I tested it and it's working.

Comment: It's also decrease speed of your webpage. It's not coding standard.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I changed the instead of email to a username so once user enter the username then based on that get the collection. In your code is getting the email after logged in.

Comment: You posted comment like " I need at the time of login based on the username get the email address". So, I updated my answer.

Comment: If it's getting answer then please upvote and approve answer. So, other user can also use this code for solve issues.